# how to draw moving rectangle in java canvas?

Tags: java, canvas

i want to make moving rectangle on Java Canvas.
And i have small problem.

I control my rectangle with KeyListener.
however, when I change its position, it only expands and does not move.
help me pls

my code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import hrozno.test.entities.*;

public class graphics {
    public static BufferStrategy bs;
    public static Graphics g;
    public graphics(){

    }
    public static void render() {
        bs = frame.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();

        if (bs == null){
            frame.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.fillRect(20,20,20,20);

        g.setColor(player.testBCGColor);
        g.fillRect(player.posX, player.posZ,player.width, player.height);

        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

before pressing W
<[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIOXy.png)img>
after pressing W
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BtEQ.png)

Comment: Clear the previous drawing.

Comment: You are drawing incorrectly.  You need to extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.  See the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) on  how to paint.  There are also examples on `keyListener` and `keybindings`